# How to connect ubuntu to external smtp on port 587?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

I have a fresh ubuntu server installation <del>with no firewall</del> and want to setup `ssmtp` to an external smtp server (e.g. smtp.mandrillapp.com:587), however, I couldn't get my server to connect to any external smtp. There seems to be something blocking all ongoing traffic to 465, 587, 25 and even 2525. I contacted my network manager and he confirmed that neither our network or our ISP do blocks traffic to that ports.

On my server I tried `telnet` against smtp.mandrillapp.com and smtp.webfaction.com but always get:

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Here's the output of `iptables-save`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3520194:592170789]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3515148:591713515]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [81776:15460174]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [43319:2857534]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2867128:427105225]
:INPUT ACCEPT [19:1392]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [38614:12612823]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [157:10183]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWIN - [0:0]
:ALLOWOUT - [0:0]
:DENYIN - [0:0]
:DENYOUT - [0:0]
:INVALID - [0:0]
:INVDROP - [0:0]
:LOCALINPUT - [0:0]
:LOCALOUTPUT - [0:0]
:LOGDROPIN - [0:0]
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.2/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.2/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.10/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.10/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.10/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.10/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.11/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.11/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.11/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 155.***.***.11/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOCALINPUT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -j INVALID
-A INPUT ! -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOGDROPIN
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.2/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.2/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.10/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.10/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.10/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.10/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.11/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.11/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.11/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 155.***.***.11/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOCALOUTPUT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -j INVALID
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8070 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT
-A INVALID -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j INVDROP
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j INVDROP
-A INVDROP -j DROP
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j ALLOWIN
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j DENYIN
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j ALLOWOUT
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j DENYOUT
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 113 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 135:139 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 135:139 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 445 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 500 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 513 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 513 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 520 -j DROP
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* "
-A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* "
-A LOGDROPIN -j DROP
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
-A LOGDROPOUT -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 21 15:56:36 2014
```

Is there somehow a setting somewhere I need to adjust before being able to connect?

Comment: please update question with output of `iptables-save`. Additionally can you check this part `nor do our ISP do that -I was able to confirmed that and I'm able to connect with my laptop.` it seems weird. Other than that if you can't connect somewhere something is blocking, if it's not your then its your ISP; or some filter on target; so to be sure it's ISP you may want to check against few different targets, best target and source you control and can be sure no firewalls on client/server exisit.

Comment: That is most certainly not "no firewall". You can't reach those sites because you have firewalled both incoming and outgoing traffic.

Comment: @michael-hampton can you please give some details on how you can to the conclusion that I have firewalled both incoming and outgoing traffic. I haven't install any firewall myself (e.g. csf) not sure if Ubuntu comes with a firewall.

Comment: Maybe you didn't install csf, but somebody certainly did, because there it is!

Comment: @MichaelHampton looks you only flagged the issue and disappeared :) would really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be something trivial, I should've allowed outgoing traffic to ports 25, 465, 587 and in the case of Mandrill 2525 as well. So edit `/etc/csf/csf.conf` and add `25,2525,465,587` to `TCP_OUT` and `TCP6_OUT`.

Source: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/csf-firewall-info.25/#post-6613